# ordenar sentencia seleccionada con JComboBox

Tags: java

Hola tengo una pregunta hay alguna forma de hacer que si yo selecciono un articulo de algun JComboBox me haga alguna funcion? osea si selecciono el articulo 1 que se imprima en pantalla hola mundo osea ese tipo de funciones, alguien que me ayude porfavor.

Comment: Hola PartyHard, por favor agrega mas detalles a tu pregunta incluyendo el código con el que estas teniendo problemas

Comment: no lo que me pregunto es si existe algun codigo que me permita seleccionar X sentencia(como por ejemplo mandar un mensaje en pantalla o lo que sea etc) usando el JComboBox es que no se mucho como se usa esa cosa

Answer (score 1):

Bueno Consegui hacer lo que queria pero tengo una pregunta como puedo hacer que el valor seleccionado lo recoja de mi BD en mysql aqui les dejo mi codigo
osea en la parte del equals("2") en lugar de verificar que el valor sea 2 que verifique que el valor sea el de alguna tabla de mi base de datos.

```
if (txtProducto.getSelectedItem().equals("2"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dos");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Este no es Dos");
    }
}
```